# How do I submit a form given only the HTML source?

Tags: python, django, testing, parsing, form-submit

I would like to be able to submit a form in an **HTML source (string)**. In other words I need at least the ability to generate POST parameters **from a string containing HTML source of the form**. This is needed in unit tests for a Django project. I would like a solution that possibly;

- Uses only standard Python library and Django.
- Allows parameter generation from a specific form if there is more than one form present.
- Allows me to change the values before submission.

A solution that returns a (Django) form instance from a given form class is best. Because it would allow me to use validation. Ideally it would consume the source (which is a string), a form class, and optionally a form name and return the instance as it was before rendering.

NOTE: I am aware this is not an easy task, and probably the gains would hardly justify the effort needed. But I am just curious about how this can be done, in a practical and reliable way. If possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should re-read the [documentation about Django's testing framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/), specifically the part about testing views (and forms) with [the test client](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#module-django.test.client).

The test client acts as a simple web browser, and lets you make `GET` and `POST` requests to your Django views. You can read the response HTML or get the same `Context` object the template received. Your `Context` object should contain the actual `forms.Form` instance you're looking for.

As an example, if your view at the URL `/form/` passes the context `{'myform': forms.Form()}` to the template, you could get to it this way:

```
from django.test.client import Client
c = Client()

# request the web page:
response = c.get('/form/')

# get the Form object:
form = response.context['myform']

form_data = form.cleaned_data
my_form_data = {} # put your filled-out data in here...
form_data.update(my_form_data)

# submit the form back to the web page:
new_form = forms.Form(form_data)
if new_form.is_valid():
    c.post('/form/', new_form.cleaned_data)
```

Hopefully that accomplishes what you want, without having to mess with parsing HTML.

**Edit**: After I re-read the Django docs about Forms, it turns out that forms are immutable. That's okay, though, just create a new `Form` instance and submit that; I've changed my code example to match this.

Comment: Great! It wouldn't occur me to look for it inside response.context for a million years. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since the Django test framework does this, I'm not sure what you're asking.

Do you want to test a Django app that has a form?

- In which case, you need to do an initial GET
- followed by the resulting POST

Do you want to write (and test) a Django app that submits a form to another site?

Here's how we test Django apps with forms.

```
class Test_HTML_Change_User( django.test.TestCase ):
    fixtures = [ 'auth.json', 'someApp.json' ]
    def test_chg_user_1( self ):
        self.client.login( username='this', password='this' )
        response= self.client.get( "/support/html/user/2/change/" )
        self.assertEquals( 200, response.status_code )
        self.assertTemplateUsed( response, "someApp/user.html")

def test_chg_user( self ):
    self.client.login( username='this', password='this' )
    # The truly fussy would redo the test_chg_user_1 test here
    response= self.client.post(
        "/support/html/user/2/change/",
        {'web_services': 'P',
         'username':'olduser',
         'first_name':'asdf',
         'last_name':'asdf',
         'email':'asdf@asdf.com',
         'password1':'passw0rd',
         'password2':'passw0rd',} )
    self.assertRedirects(response, "/support/html/user/2/" )
    response= self.client.get( "/support/html/user/2/" )
    self.assertContains( response, "<h2>Users: Details for", status_code=200 )
    self.assertContains( response, "olduser" )
    self.assertTemplateUsed( response, "someApp/user_detail.html")
```

Note - we don't parse the HTML in detail.  If it has the right template and has the right response string, it has to be right.

Comment: I can't see the part where this code extracts any form instance from the response content?

Comment: Added another example.  Can't figure out what you want.  It's best to run through the scenario you want to see as a code sample (even if it doesn't work).  Specifics and details help.

Comment: @S.Lott: so the second parameter to TestCase.client.post is the POST dictionary right? Suppose I would like to do this; self.client.post(url, extract_form_params(response.content, 'form_name'))
Or better; form_instance = extract_form(response.content, 'form_name', MyForm)
Please `read` the question.

Comment: @muhuk: I read the question. It has too many "possibly" and "ideally" things.  Please break it down into simple, numbered steps of what must happen.  form_instance=... means what?  Is that a POST or a GET?  Or is that part of an assertion?

Comment: @S.Lott: `form_instance` is simply a django.forms.forms.Form instance. :D

Comment: @Muhuk: In a test?  Is it part of a GET, a POST or an assert?  What are you trying to do?  Are you trying to test a Django app?  If so, you can only POST or GET, you can only make an assertion about the response.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

It is simple... and hard at the same time.
Disclaimer: I don't know much about Python and nothing at all about Django... So I give general, language agnostic advices...
If one of the above advices doesn't work for you, you might want to do it manually:

- Load the page with an HTML parser, list the forms.
- If the `method` attribute is POST (case insensitive), get the `action` attribute to get the URL of the request (can be relative).
- In the form, get all `input` and `select` tags. The `name` (or `id` if no name) attributes are the keys of the request parameters. The `value` attributes (empty if absent) are the corresponding values.
- For `select`, the value is the one of the selected `option` or the displayed text is no `value` attribute.

These names and values must be URL encoded in GET requests, but not in POST ones.

HTH.

Comment: Your solution involves some amount of work, but nothing complicated. I should start looking into htmllib and HTMLParser libraries. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) or it's wrapper [twill](http://twill.idyll.org/).  I think it's [ClientForm](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/ClientForm/) module will work for you.

Comment: I know these work well, and they would solve this problem in some other environment. But I'd like to create a Django app, with no dependencies other than Django and Python. Simply because this is just for Django testing. But thanks a lot for mentioning them.

Comment: Gotcha... although, note that with Python you can install mechanize under your Django's project's directory and import off it's namespace.  (If redistribution or deployment is your concern)